# Replace Dataframe Column Values with User Defined Function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I have a grouped set of values in a column I am trying to replace with a since value

```
col1
a
a;a;b;c
c;b;a
NA
b;b;b
```

I want to replace all values with either `mixed` or the single present value if for example `a;a;a;a` becomes `a`

Expected Output

```
col1
a
Mixed
Mixed
NA
b
```

Code

```
grouping = function(x){
y = as.list(strsplit(x, ";")[[1]])

#select first element, and test if each is the same element.
z = ""
for (i in 1:length(y)){
  if (as.character(y[1]) != as.character(y[i])) {
    z = 'mixed'
    break
  } else {
    z = as.character(y[1])
  }
}
return(z)
}

db %>%
select(col1) %>%
mutate(
test = grouping(col1)
)
```

I have tried it a few different ways and either end up with it not working at all or giving the value `a` for everything

Comment: Good call, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option via defining a user function `f`

```
f <- function(x) ifelse(length(u <- unique(unlist((strsplit(x, ";"))))) > 1, "Mixed", u)
```

such that

```
> transform(df, col1 = Vectorize(f)(col1))
   col1
1     a
2 Mixed
3 Mixed
4  <NA>
5     b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also consider this for your function and use `base R`:

```
#Function  
myfun <- function(x)
{
  y <- unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))
  if(length(unique(y))==1)
  {
    z <- unique(y)
  } else
  {
    z <- 'Mixed'
  }
}
#Apply
df$New <- apply(df,1,myfun)
```

Output:

```
df
     col1   New
1       a     a
2 a;a;b;c Mixed
3   c;b;a Mixed
4    <NA>  <NA>
5   b;b;b     b
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a;a;b;c", "c;b;a", NA, "b;b;b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the substring from the 'col1' which are letters, check the number of distinct elements with `n_distinct`, use `case_when` to change those which have more one unique elements to 'Mixed'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(col1 = case_when(map_dbl(str_extract_all(col1,
         "[a-z]"), n_distinct) >1 ~ "Mixed",
       is.na(col) ~ NA_character_, 
      TRUE ~ substr(col1, 1, 1)))
```

-output

```
#  col1
#1     a
#2 Mixed
#3 Mixed
#4  <NA>
#5     b
```

---

Or another option is to split the column by the delimiter with `separate_rows`, and do a group by `row_number` to `summarise` elements having more than one row (after the `distinct`) to be 'Mixed'

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   separate_rows(col1) %>% 
   distinct() %>%
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   summarise(col1 = case_when(n() > 1 ~ 'Mixed', TRUE ~ first(col1)), 
        .groups = 'drop') %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
#  col1 
#  <chr>
#1 a    
#2 Mixed
#3 Mixed
#4 <NA> 
#5 b
```

---

Or using `base R` with a compact option

```
v1 <- gsub("([a-z])\\1+", "\\1", gsub(";", "", df1$col1))
replace(v1, nchar(v1) > 1, "Mixed")
#[1] "a"     "Mixed" "Mixed" NA      "b"
```

---

The issue in the OP's function is that it is extracting only the first `[[1]]` `list` element

```
as.list(strsplit(x, ";")[[1]])
```

as `strsplit` returns a `list` with `length` equal to the number of rows of the initial data.  So, basically by selecting only the first, it is recycled

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a;a;b;c", "c;b;a", NA, "b;b;b")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the `grouping` function as :

```
grouping <- function(x) {
  sapply(strsplit(x, ';'), function(x) 
        if(length(unique(x)) == 1) unique(x) else 'Mixed')
}
db$test <- grouping(db$col1)
db

#     col1  test
#1       a     a
#2 a;a;b;c Mixed
#3   c;b;a Mixed
#4    <NA>  <NA>
#5   b;b;b     b
```